# WPF Click on control inside ListBoxItem does not select ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

Hi I could not find any similar problem so I posted new question. In code below I create ListBox control with ListBoxItems that each contains radio button inside. When I click on the radio button it gets selects but parent ListBoxItem does not (ListBoxItem is not highlighted). How can I solve this issue?

```
<ListBox Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding mySource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Rabio template -->
            <RadioButton GroupName="radiosGroup"
                     Margin="10, 2, 5, 2"
                     Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedSetting}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding SomeId, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Content="{Binding FileNameWithoutExtensions, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by applying the following `ItemContainerStyle` to your `ListBox` which uses `Trigger` on property `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` to select it.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Style.Triggers> 
           <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"> 
              <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/> 
           </Trigger> 
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: One problem with this is that it will unselect the item when it loses keyboard focus. This is not advisable if you have a Multi selectionMode.

Answer (score 0):

I have a listbox that displays `ListBoxItem`s vertically, horizontally, and has all sorts of child buttons contained within each `ListBoxItem`.

The problem I ran into (like others) is when you click on a child button contained in the `ListBoxItem`, the `ListBoxItem` is not selected and you can not get the `ListBoxItem.SelectedIndex` value (because clicking on the button does not select the `ListBoxItem`).

I had some problems implementing the above xaml code because clicking on my `GroupBox` header would cause my selected `ListBoxItem` to lose focus.

The best solution I found on the web for this problem was to add a couple lines of code to the button's mouse click event to determine the parent control and then set the `ListBoxItem.IsSelected = true`.

After this is done, the `ListBoxItem.SelectedIndex` will contain the correct index value for the item selected.  In my code, DataContext is set on the Listbox like this: `DataContext="{StaticResource VM_Programs}"`

Here's the VB code behind for the button event:

```
Private Sub YourButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim clicked As Object = (TryCast(e.OriginalSource, FrameworkElement)).DataContext
    Dim lbitem As ListBoxItem
    lbitem = YourListboxName.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(clicked)
    lbitem.IsSelected = True
    MsgBox("The listbox item (" + YourListboxName.SelectedIndex.ToString + ") is now selected")
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe this question relates to C#