# How to bind command when button inside of ListBox Item

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have button inside of ListBox

```
 <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" >
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>

                                             <StackPanel>
                                                                <Button Command="{Binding Remove}" />
                                                                <Button Command="{Binding Change}"/>
                                                            </StackPanel>


                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
```

In ViewModel

```
  public Command Remove{ get { return new Command(true, new System.Action(RemoveCmd)); } }
    public Command Change{ get { return new Command(true, new System.Action(ChangeCmd)); } }
```

Method is not fired when i click button. How can i fix that?

Comment: It is looking for these commands inside of your user objects (the items that you have bound to ItemsSource)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use binding in the ListBox’s Items to the ViewModel’s properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500729/how-to-use-binding-in-the-listbox-s-items-to-the-viewmodel-s-properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your Command-Binding to:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.Remove, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.Change, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
```

Comment: It works, but when i click button selected item is not changed. When I click button selected item should be item which contains clicked button. Is it possible?

Comment: If you only have singleselection mode active inside your ListBox, then you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159382/wpf-click-on-control-inside-listboxitem-does-not-select-listboxitem